# Shut down jupyter notebook kernels on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I would like to shut down notebook kernels on VS Code.

I'm moving to VS Code from Jupyter Hub where I shut kernels down from the left sidebar (see image).[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfpv2.png)

How could I do that on VS Code?

Comment: That's weird. There seems to be no keyboard interrupt or stop button in VS Code

Answer (score 5):

I see a restart option in VS code as shown in the screenshot (red box)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that might help:

- If you have the notebook open you can restart the kernel (not the same thing, but release most of the memory)
- If you have closed the notebook, you can re-open it. Then you can click restart.

## Alternative to restart the computer:

**Not recommended, but if you find no alternative,** you can try to kill all processes: `pkill -f "jupyter"`. **Make sure you have nothing important running there.**.

It seems like a major oversight. I usually have many notebooks open, and it is ridiculous that I need to have a whole kernel for each of them.

Comment: I have the same issue, restarting VSCODE also seems to work (a better option if I have other kernels running that I don't want to kill) but I am also looking for a better option